# Input loses focus when typing and only allows one character

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component which receives an array with some string properties and a component

```
const FormWizardItems = [
    {
      title: "Organization Data",
      number: 1,
      component: () => (
        <CustomerOrganizationDataTabContentFrm validation={validation} />
      ),
    }
  ]

  return (
    <>
      <FormWizard
        validation={validation}
        apiCallResponse={registrationError}
        breadcrumbTitle="Clientes"
        breadcrumbItemTitle="Register Customer"
        cardTitle="Clientes"
        cardDescription="Register Customer"
        items={FormWizardItems}
      />
    </>
  )
```

The FormWizard component internally passes each component to another component (FormWizardContent) which renders all the components from the received array

```
<CardBody>
                  <h4 className="card-title mb-4">{cardTitle}</h4>
                  <div className="wizard clearfix">    
                    <div className="steps clearfix">
                      <ul>
                        {items.map(item => {
                          return (
                            <FormWizardNavItem
                              key={item.number}
                              number={item.number}
                              title={item.title}
                              activeTab={activeTab}
                              passedSteps={passedSteps}
                              setActiveTab={setActiveTab}
                            />
                          )
                        })}
                      </ul>
                    </div>
                    <div className="content clearfix">
                      <TabContent activeTab={activeTab} className="body">
                        {items.map(item => {
                          const Component = item.component

                          return (
                            <FormWizardContent
                              key={item.number}
                              tabId={item.number}
                              activeTab={activeTab}
                              component={() => (
                                <Component exampleProp="Hello" />
                              )}
                            />
                          )
                        })}
                      </TabContent>
                    </div>
```

FormWizardContent Component

```
import React from "react"
import { TabPane } from "reactstrap"

export const FormWizardContent = props => {
  const { tabId, component: Component } = props
  return (
    <TabPane tabId={tabId}>
      <Component />
    </TabPane>
  )
}
```

The Form it renders (CustomerOrganizationDataTabContentFrm) is a form with a dependency prop (validation) coming from parent Component (CustomerFrm)

```
const validation = useFormik({
    enableReinitialize: true,

    initialValues: {
      BusinessName: "",
      TradingName: "",
      EinItin: "",
      StateEin: "",
      OtherTaxPayerStateEin: "",
      CityEin: "",
      CompanyCategory: "",
      HeadquarterId: null,
      IsActive: true,
    },
    validationSchema: Yup.object({
      BusinessName: Yup.string()
        .required("Business Name is required")
        .min(3, "Business Name should have at minimun of 3 characters")
        .max(3, "Business Name should have up to 3 characters")
      TradingName: Yup.string()
        .required("Trading Name is required")
        .min(3, "Trading Name should have at minimun of 3 characters")
        .max(3, "Trading Name should have up to 3 characters"),
    }),
    onSubmit: values => {
      dispatch(registerRole(values))
    },
  })
```

The problem is that when i type in the input it only allows one character and loses focus, i can't manage it to work properly, any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I would recommend simplifying your code to only what is necessary. Glad you solved it though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the problem, the reason was the anonymous render functions in these two parts of the code

```
const FormWizardItems = [
    {
      title: "Organization Data",
      number: 1,
      component: () => (
        <CustomerOrganizationDataTabContentFrm validation={validation} />
      ),
    }
  ]

<TabContent activeTab={activeTab} className="body">
  {items.map((item) => {
    const Component = item.component;

    return (
      <FormWizardContent
        key={item.number}
        tabId={item.number}
        activeTab={activeTab}
        component={() => <Component exampleProp="Hello" />}
      />
    );
  })}
</TabContent>;
```

According to what I've seen, whenever there was some state changes a new form was generated and rendered instead of reender the existing instance.

Solved it this way

```
[{
  title: "Organization Data",
  number: 1,
  component: CustomerOrganizationDataTabContentFrm,
}]

<TabContent activeTab={activeTab} className="body">
      {items.map(item => {
      return (
      <FormWizardContent
      key={item.number}
      tabId={item.number}
      activeTab={activeTab}
      validation={validation}
      component={item.component}
    />
  )
})}
```